# How to create a timer that resets for quiz games?

Tags: python, pygame

I trying to create a timer for my quiz game. It should reset after every right question. But problem with my code is that it keeps increasing speed after every time it resets.

```
timeCount = 30
def countdown():
   global timeCount
   while timeCount > 0:
      print(timeCount)
      sleep(1)
      timeCount -= 1
   else:
      print("Time Out!")
```

Comment: How do you reset the timer? And can you provide more detail about what you mean by 'increasing speed'?

Comment: Not very sure how you're currently resetting the timer, could you be a bit clearer?

Comment: I just reset timeCount to 30. Like,   timeCount = 30

Comment: Please provide an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
import time

timeCount = 30
start = time.time()
seconds = 0
def countdown():
   global timeCount
   global seconds
   while seconds  < timeCount:
       now = time.time()
       seconds = now - start
       print(timeCount - seconds)
   else:
      print("Time Out!")

countdown()
```

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_time.htm) teaches you how to use time.time. You can take away `seconds` from `timeCount` to make a timer that goes down from 30 to 0. When the `seconds` hits 30, you can end the loop and print "Time out". You can truncate the unnecessary floating point values, since i am assuming floating point numbers doesn't look good on a quiz timer and is unnecessary as well.

```
seconds = int(seconds)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function time.perf_counter() :

```
import time

start=time.perf_counter()
time.sleep(1) #you can replace the sleep function with the action you want to monitor
end=time.perf_counter()

print('elapsed time : ',end-start)
```

In the example above, time.perf_counter() evaluated the time when it is called so it gives you the elapsed time between the two call.

**if you want to use your current logic :**

Your 'global' statement means that your are going to modify the 'timeCount' variable during the execution of your code. To fix it, you can use a new local variable in your function (called 'local_count' in the below solution), like this you reset the countdown each time you call your function :

```
import time

timeCount = 30
def countdown():
   local_count = timeCount
   while local_count > 0:
      print(local_count)
      time.sleep(1)
      local_count -= 1
   print("Time Out!")
```